# Sharding key (MongoDB) for large number documents

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am developing a web application where users will be uploading a large number of documents to the system and different types of operations will be performed on the documents, including aggregation. However the number of documents uploaded by each user varies widely - some might upload a dozen documents, and some might upload a million documents.

documents look something like this:

```
doc{
    _id: <self generated UUID>,
    uid: <id of user who uploaded the document>,
    ctime: <creation timestamp>,
    ....
        <other attributes, etc>
    ....
}
```

Now here is the problem in choosing the shard key:
1. If I choose the UUID as the shard key, documents uploaded by the same user are unlikely to end up in the same shard and aggregation operations will be costly.
2. If I use uid as the shard key then the data stored in shards will not be even.

Can anyone suggest which is the best way to achieve this?

I am very new to partitioning and sharding and my research on google as well as stack-overflow did not yield anything. I can change the schema of the documents if needed since the project is still at the design phase.

Comment: How do you want to query the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best guide I've seen on choosing a shard key: http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/

You have to decide how you want to query the data. Perhaps a combination of uid and ctime will yield a good shard key, but I'm not sure if that will cause you grief while querying, as you haven't given much insight on how you plan to query.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am going thru it now, but it seems a bit confusing.

I want to query the data based on either the UUID, or a combination of (uid,parentid). That's all - rest of the fields change from document to document anyways. FYI the parent is the id of the parent document (like wordpress pages). 

However I will run some functions like count_child_docs(parentid) which will recursively scan the 'tree'. This is why I want to have the data on a single shard as much as possible.

I thought of creating the key on (uid,parentid) but parentid can change, so updates might be costly.

Comment: I went thru the article again and played with the demo provided there. I think the best key for my case would be (uid, UUID). But I guess will have to keep the chunk size small to optimize for user's with very low number of uploads.
@wes-freeman : What's your opinion?

Comment: Your idea sounds good. Definitely worth giving it a shot in a test--make sure you test inserts (to make sure they don't all go to the same shard) and queries (to make sure they mostly go to 1-2 shards and avoid a lot of merging). I don't think you need to keep the chunk size small, though. Can your uuid queries include the uid, or is that not known?

Answer (score 1):

You can read more on shardkey selection and scaling

1] Kristina Chodrow's book "Scaling MongoDB"
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018308.do

2]Antoine Girbal's presentation on Sharding Best Practices
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Sharding-Best-Practices-Advanced