# Shard key and how to choose it?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm new in NoSQL databases and now I use MongoDB, BTW I have a question about MongoDB shard key and I want to know what it does actually? Is it related to queries performance? And how we can choose a good shard key for a collection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 10gen's docs: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key

Choosing a shard-key is very dependent on your data and your use case.

Here's some more documentation you may find relevant:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

Specifically:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/

Essentially sharding allows you to partition your data across different servers. This means different writes/reads are going to different servers -- distributing the load of the application across multiple servers.

The shard key is the value in the collection that you are evaluating to determine which shard/server the document is being routed too.

Comment: While pointing to the docs is a valid response, the advice to chose ID (assuming you meant _id which is by default ObjectID based) is not very good.  It even says so on the document page you linked in the "Write Scaling" section. Picking what is essentially a time based monotonically increasing shard key can be horrible for write performance, depending on the profile of the data ingestion.

Comment: @Ranman: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me what the Shard keys does and how it works?

Comment: Also thanks @AdamC for pointing all of that out. Sorry for my initial lame response.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more explanation on shard key selection and working in Kristina Chodrow's book "Scaling MongoDB"

Check out [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029530/1424605) also